# Как изменить иконку в зависимости от выбранной темы?

Tags: android, android-xml, атрибуты, android-style, android-themes

В файле **attrs.xml** у меня прописано название для темной и светлой темы

```
<resources>
    <attr name="theme_type" format="string"/>
    <attr name="tab_menu_home_icon" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

Соответственно в файле **themes.xml** описаны иконки для темной и светлой темы

```
<resources>

    <style name="Coders.LightTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="theme_type">light</item>
        <item name="tab_menu_home_icon">@drawable/ic_menu_fragment_home_light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Coders.DarkTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="theme_type">dark</item>
        <item name="tab_menu_home_icon">@drawable/ic_menu_fragment_home_dark</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

И уже в xml разметке Activity в **ImageView** я устанавливаю иконку из атрибутов

```
android:src="?tab_menu_home_icon"
```

После чего, сетаплю в активность тему либо **light** либо **dark** и цвет иконки менется. Такой способ работает отлично. Но что делать если мне нужно указывать имя иконки не в файле xml, а программно?

По идее должно быть как то так, но не работает

```
    iconTabImageView.setImageResource(R.attr.tab_menu_home_icon);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277618/get-color-value-programmatically-when-its-a-reference-theme

Answer (score 0):

Нашел код на GitHub, который отлично решает мою проблему.

```
public class ResUtil {

    public static int getDrawableRes(Context c, @AttrRes int attr) {
        return getDrawableRes(c.getTheme(), attr);
    }

    public static int getDrawableRes(Resources.Theme theme, @AttrRes int attr) {
        final TypedValue out = new TypedValue();
        theme.resolveAttribute(attr, out, true);
        return out.resourceId;
    }

    public static Drawable getDrawable(Context c, @AttrRes int attr) {
        return ContextCompat.getDrawable(c, getDrawableRes(c, attr));
    }
}
```